# databricks CSV import timestamp NULL issue

Tags: csv, null, timestamp, databricks

I'm trying to follow `Databricks` Academy Spark SQL course and I'm practising in `Databricks` community edition. At a point, I need to create a table from a CSV. [This is CSV link.](https://scorm.servicerocket.io/packages/5d1d1af4-32e1-419b-9a7a-bc0072bf36df/scormcontent/assets/jr3nR6SVli5WkUJO_3K79QKQWrnv-4ijA-people.csv)

I'm trying to create the table with UI. I'm checking "First row is header" and "Infer Schema" boxes. `birthDate` field is being shown as String in the preview pane. According to the course material, it should be Timestamp. But if I change field type to Timestamp, the data is loaded with null values. If I leave the `birthDate` field as it was (`String`), data is loading properly.

How can I deal with this issue?

Sample data in `birthDate` field :

> 1999-09-13T04:00:00.000+0000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inferSchema` for CSV file [expects data in the specific format](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVOptions.scala#L138): `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`, and the `XXX` pattern is matching to [following specification of the timezone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html): `Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;`, that doesn't match your data.

To fix this you may revert to the creating a table via notebook, and add following option to specify the timestamp format: `.option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")`, the whole read command would look as following:

```py
df = spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
    .load(path_to_file)
```

Another possibility is to load the data, and then to use `to_timestamp` on the necessary column - it has better auto-detection capabilities than CSV `infrerSchema`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, col
df = spark.read.format("csv")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load(path_to_file)
    .withColumn("birthDate", to_timestamp(col("birthDate")))
```